# Maglev Modelling and Control System Design

Tags: control, modelling

Im trying to model a Maglev system (schematic seen below) the system paramentres are below aswell.

[image]
[image]

Im aiming to try and get a state space represetation for the system. This is what i have done by hand so far, please excuse my handwriting. Could someone possibly correct me if im wrong or a mistake is made.

States of the system are
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The question is too broad. You seem to be using a ready-made maglev experiment test setup (made for educational purposes). The user manual for the setup would usually have the model. Compare your model to that one.

Comment: How did `g` which is an *external force* (equation 4) finally end up multiplying with `x_2` ? Equation 7 also indicates that `g` appears alone; i.e., not multiplied with any state. I think `g` should appear in a fashion similar to `u` as it is similar to an *input* (which is decided by earth rather than the user).